# Choice Field That Hides Other List Form Fields

Tags: choice-field

This is for SharePoint 2010

I would like to know how to make a choice field on a list that could hide other fields, depending on what is picked in the choice field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't that functionality out of the box, but it can be done with custom javascript or editing the forms with InfoPath.